# How do you reference the entire google spreadsheet into another?

Tags: google-sheets

So, I have two workbooks, one with multiple sheets(W1) and one empty(W2)
I want the empty one (W2) to have all the data (all strings, chars, and SHEETS) that (W1) has.

`IMPORTRANGE` only takes data from a single sheet of a workbook, and I am not interested in that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "reference" a whole workbook into another by using built-in formulas or custom functions, the alternative is to use Google Apps Script, the Sheets API or an Add-on to copy the sheets and values from one workbook to the other.

Built-in and custom functions only are able to return values, they can't create sheets and cant't modify spreadsheets, sheets and cell settings/properties.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/